# Meaning of two const in C/C++ signature

Tags: c++, constants, signature

I've been wrapping a gl file for `scheme` and it failed twice in the `gl.h` header. I'm on OSx so it might be platform dependent, but I never seen this syntax anywhere else in my life.

```
typedef void (* glMultiDrawElementsProcPtr) (GLenum mode, const GLsizei *count, GLenum type, const GLvoid* const *indices, GLsizei primcount);
```

Notice the `const GLvoid* const *indices`. The scheme C interpreter has a small C subset and doesn't understand this part of the header.

What does it mean and how can I safely replace it by something else... I changed it to

`const GLvoid** indices`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Types in C and C++ are read from right to left except that most people insist in placing the `const` on the wrong side. Once you fixed the `const` placement from

```
const GLvoid* const*
```

to

```
GLvoid const* const*
```

it becomes trivial to read the type: It is a pointer to a `const` pointer to a `const` object of type `GLvoid` (you probably can't really have ovjects of type `GLvoid` but it's the placeholder for any object). You can also have the combinations where the inner pointer is modifiable and/or the object is modifiable depending on which `const` you leave out.

Comment: `const GLvoid*` may be "wrong" according to C parsing rule or whatever rules, but it is natural English order to place an adjective before the noun.

Comment: @C.R.: It isn't _wrong_ in the C or C++ language sense but it is wrong with respect to reading types, i.e., in the natural English sense: while the reading direction doesn't matter for primitive type (you can read, e.g., `int` from left to right or from right to left and it won't make any difference), types in C and C++ are read from right to left, e.g., `int*` is a "pointer to int". If you now add `const` into the picture, which is more natural: `const int*`, i.e., a pointer to `int` constant, or `int const*`, i.e., a [non-constant] pointer to to constant `int`?

Answer (score 0):

This means that `indices` is a pointer to a `const GLvoid * const`.

The datatype above can also be written as `GLvoid const * const`.  This tells us that neither the data pointed to by the `GLvoid*` pointer, nor the pointer itself may be modified.

There is no such restriction on `indices` itself.  You may modify the pointer to the `GLvoid*`.