# Two "const" in c++ variable declaration

Tags: c++

I came across this code in win32 API programming tutorial and I am struggling to understand it.

```
if (msg == WM_NCCREATE) 
{
    const CREATESTRUCTW* const pCreate = reinterpret_cast<CREATESTRUCTW*>(lParam);
}
```

What does `const CREATESTRUCTW* const pCreate` mean?

I did find [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18972943/meaning-of-two-const-in-c-c-signature) answer while doing my research. The example provided in that question was :

```
const GLvoid* const *indices
```

and a summary of the accepted answer is:

The correct way to write it is `GLvoid const* const*` and the correct way to read it is from right to left which reads:

" It is a pointer to a const pointer to a const object of type GLvoid ".

This confused me even more because no matter how I read it, reading it from right to left reads:

" It is a const pointer(const*) to a const pointer(const*) to an object of type GLvoid(GLvoid)".

It would also be nice if anyone could explain it in terms of my question i.e. `const CREATESTRUCTW* const pCreate`. Thanks.

Comment: Sometimes declarations could be hard to comprehend. I think using spiral rule can help in decrypting declaration meaning. See "C++/C Spiral Rule", like here http://c-faq.com/decl/spiral.anderson.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's rewrite this

```
   const CREATESTRUCTW* const pCreate
```

into this:

```
   CREATESTRUCTW const * const pCreate
// <------- a -------> <- b ->
```

which means the same thing.

`const` refers to the thing to the left, so you have an immutable pointer (`b`) that is pointing to an immutable object of type `CREATESTRUCTW` (`a`).

Answer (score 2):

Let's take that apart ...

- `CREATESTRUCTW* pCreate` - `pCreate` is a pointer to an object of type `CREATESTRUCTW`
- `const CREATESTRUCTW* pCreate` - `pCreate` is a pointer to a **const** object of type `CREATESTRUCTW`
- `const CREATESTRUCTW* const pCreate` - `pCreate` itself is const, once a value has been assigned to it, it can't be changed

Answer (score 1):

> `const CREATESTRUCTW* const pCreate`

The pointer pCreate is unmodifiable, and the `CREATESTRUCTW` it points to cannot be modified via `pCreate`.

That is after declaration:

```
pCreate = NULL ; // will fail to compile
```

and also:

```
pCreate->style = WS_BORDER ; // will also fail to compile
```

essentially it provides read-only protection for the pointer and for what it points to.

Note that while the `CREATESTRUCTW` object is unmodifieble via this pointer, it could be modifiable via a non-const pointer to the same object.

> `const GLvoid* const *indices`

Is a const pointer to a const pointer to `GLvoid`.  That is like a `GLvoid**` but where `indices` is unmodifieable and `*indices` is modifiable. The `GLvoid` object `**indices` is however modifiable.

> The correct way to write it is GLvoid const* const* ...

That is nonsense; that is an *alternative*, but `const GLvoid* const *indices` is no less *correct*, and more idiomatic.  Which is easier to understand in a matter of opinion.